# Why is there no compilation error?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

When i am compiling the code below,it is running without any errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct adjacency
{
    struct node* dest;
    struct adjacency* link;
};
struct node
{
    char nodename;
    struct node* next;
    struct adjacency* adj;
};
int main( void )
{
    //code
}
```

But why?I think it should show  compilation error for not having defined struct node before it has been used inside struct adjacency..But it is running perfectly alright..What's the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code. `struct node` inside `adjacency` say that there's a struct named `node`, and `struct node*` says that `adjacency` hold a pointer to `struct node`. You don't need a complete type (that's the formal term for a type whose definition has not been seen) to declare a pointer. If `adjacency` had a member `struct node link;` you'd get an error.

Comment: what about the scope of struct node?

Comment: Like most declarations, the scope is the block in which the declaration occurs. (I originally said "all declarations", but there are cases in which a declaration inside a class injects a name into an outer scope; this is not one of those)

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows you to have *pointers* to incomplete types.  `struct node *dest` is just such a beast.  You have a forward reference to `struct node`, but since you're only declaring a pointer to that type, the compiler doesn't mind.  This is explicitly allowed, and it enables building structures that refer to each other.

If you need two classes or structs that refer to each other in C++ but do not want to use the `struct` or `class` keyword in the declaration, you can make a tentative declaration:

```
struct node;       // Incomplete type, but makes `node` known to compiler as a struct.
struct adjacency;  // Incomplete type, but makes `adjacency` known to compiler as a struct.

struct adjacency
{
    node *dest;
    adjacency *link;
};

struct node
{
    char nodename;
    node *next;
    adjacency *adj;
};
```

Stylistic guide:  Put the * next to the variable name, not the type.  That's how the compiler sees it, and it'll save you confusion later when you write something like `struct node* next, prev;`, and wonder why `prev` isn't a pointer.  The idiomatic way to write that is `struct node *next, *prev;`.

Comment: A lot of C++ code (probably most of it) uses the `struct node* next` style -- or rather `node* next`, since C++ doesn't require the `struct` keyword when referring to the type. It doesn't reflect the grammar, but it doesn't cause a problem if declare just one object per line, which is a good idea anyway: write `node* next; node* prev;` rather than `node *next, *prev;`. (I personally prefer to put the `*` next to the name, and most C code does it that way; the usual C++ style is influenced by Stroustrup's own preference.)

Comment: Hmmm... I have been noticing the "star next to the type" more often, but still most of the code I interact with it has "star next to the name."  It wouldn't be the first place Stroustrup and I have parted ways stylistically.  He's also moved to proportionally-spaced code...